# Update a table column using postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `base` which I need to update after a record has been inserted. I have written a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION host_ip() RETURNS trigger AS $host_ip$
BEGIN

    update  base set thumbnail_url =
    replace ("thumbnail_url",'localhost','myipadd') WHERE id = NEW.id;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$host_ip$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function is giving me errors when a record is inserted. I have a trigger which calls the function after insert. The error is `PL/pgSQL function host_ip() line 4 at SQL statement SQL statement`

The trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER host_ip AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE   ON base
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE host_ip();
```

Comment: I have added the trigger

Answer (score 1):

To change the column of the just inserted or updated row, you only need to *assign* the value. There is no need to run an `update`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION host_ip() RETURNS trigger 
AS 
$host_ip$
BEGIN
   new.thumbnail_url := replace(thumbnail_url,'localhost','myipadd');
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$host_ip$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But you can't change the value in an AFTER trigger, you need a `BEFORE` trigger for this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER host_ip 
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON base
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE host_ip();
```